Understanding effect of redirecting output of a function call that makes variable mutation not visible
I observed a weird behavior in zsh 5.9 in mac. (Following is a simplification to reproduce the error, it does not try to make sense).
If I execute in a terminal
$> function assigner() { OPTIONS=mutated } 
$> function main() { typeset OPTIONS; assigner; echo $OPTIONS }  
$> main

This outputs:
mutated

But if I subtly change main function to redirect output of the inner function call...
$> function main() { typeset OPTIONS; assigner | cat; echo $OPTIONS }

Then the result is blank
And my OPTIONS var is not populated anymore.
What is happening here?

just to reassure you: that's not specific to mac os, happens on Linux as well. It would seem | puts things in independent subshells, but I don't know where that is reflected

Yes, it seems so... my apologies

A pipe is an inter-process communication mechanism.
In a A | B pipeline, A and B run concurrently with the standard output of A connected to the standard input of B via a pipe.
So they have to run in separate processes. In most shells, they both run in child processes; in zsh like in original implementations of ksh, only A runs in a child process (though if B is an external command it will still be executed in a child process of course).
So in assigner | cat, since assigner is running in a child shell process, it's only modifying the variables of that subshell, not that of the parent shell process. When the pipeline terminates, the changes to the variables are lost.
Here, if you wanted assigner to run in the parent process but still have its output piped to cat (running in a separate process), you could redirect assigner's output to a process substitution running cat:
assigner > >(cat)

Or run cat as a co-process:
Co-processes have both their stdin and stdout redirected to a pipe so the main process can both feed data to them and get date from them, but you can cancel the stdout part by saving and restoring the original stdout using an extra file descriptor.
assigner() OPTIONS=mutated

{ coproc cat >&3 3>&-; } 3>&1 # start cat as coproc with stdout restored
cat_pid=$!                    # record its pid
assigner >&p                  # run assigner with stdout redirected to coproc
coproc :                      # dummy coproc to close the pipes to the
                              # previous one.
wait $cat_pid                 # make sure cat has returned before running
                              # the next commands.
echo $OPTIONS                 

(see How do you use the command coproc in various shells? for more details on how to use co-processes).
Alternatively, you could make use of the variable that assigner sets in the same subshell where it is run, again making the original stdout available there using a separate fd:
assigner() OPTIONS=mutated

{
  {
    assigner
    echo $OPTIONS >&3
  } | cat
} 3>&1

